# Url in a blog post django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

https://github.com/nathanborror/django-basic-apps/blob/master/README.rst I am trying to implement this blog module my question is that the i am writing one generic function and when i fetch a blog get a url as

```
def Myfunc(request):
  p = Post.objects.get(pk=12)
  p.get_absolute_url //This prints blog/2011/jun/13/fgfgf/
```

My question is that how to get the url with the domain name or where does this being handled in the code..

`EDIT: i.e, http://mysite.com/blog/2011/jun/13/fgfgf/`

The models field is as,

```
  class Post(models.Model):
      """Post model."""
      STATUS_CHOICES = (
          (1, _('Draft')),
          (2, _('Public')),
      )
      title = models.CharField(_('title'), max_length=200)
      slug = models.SlugField(_('slug'), unique_for_date='publish')
      author = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
      body = models.TextField(_('body'), )
      tease = models.TextField(_('tease'), blank=True, help_text=_('Concise text suggested. Does not appear in RSS feed.'))
      status = models.IntegerField(_('status'), choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=2)
      allow_comments = models.BooleanField(_('allow comments'), default=True)
      publish = models.DateTimeField(_('publish'), default=datetime.datetime.now)
      created = models.DateTimeField(_('created'), auto_now_add=True)
      modified = models.DateTimeField(_('modified'), auto_now=True)
      categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, blank=True)
      #created_by = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
      tags = TagField()
      objects = PublicManager()

      class Meta:
          verbose_name = _('post')
          verbose_name_plural = _('posts')
          db_table  = 'blog_posts'
          ordering  = ('-publish',)
          get_latest_by = 'publish'

      def __unicode__(self):
          return u'%s' % self.title

      @permalink
      def get_absolute_url(self):
          return ('blog_detail', None, {
              'year': self.publish.year,
              'month': self.publish.strftime('%b').lower(),
              'day': self.publish.day,
              'slug': self.slug
          })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the sites framework to get the fully qualified url - as per https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/contrib/sites/

Comment: cant we do the same with django 1.2.1 version